# copyItemAtPath -path shows null for plist created in background thread

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

I have a function that checks whether the plist exists or not, if not it will create the plist.

this function is called in background i.e
`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(CreatePlist:) withObject:xyz];`

everything goes just perfect.

but when i try to fetch the data from the plist on main thread i.e

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"calendar" ofType:@"plist"];
NSLog(@"path is %@", path); // path comes null
fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
NSLog(@"file name data contain %@",fileName);
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

//see if Data.plist exists in the Documents directory
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self saveMyPath:fileName] ]) {
    [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:[self saveMyPath:@""] error:nil]; //at this point the app crashes saying path is null
}
```

when i moved my application from the background to the main thread it works well.
what is the problem here.?

Comment: What do you use as a barrier to ensure the writing is complete before you attempt to read? Can you show the code that implements `-CreatePlist:` and what you're using as a barrier?

Comment: well when the file is created means the plist I call a function on the main thread and set the parameter `waitUntilDone:YES`

Comment: please show that code. How do you signal your main thread that the file has been created? Please edit your question to include the implementation of `-CreatePlist:` if you want real useful help.

Comment: Actually, just use what @MikeK wrote. It's what I would have probably suggested anyway and it will do what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like the background thread isn't finished when the main thread gets to it.

you could try using grand central dispatch.. e.g.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{
  [self CreatePlist:xyz];
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"calendar" ofType:@"plist"];
    NSLog(@"path is %@", path); // path comes null
    fileName = [fileName stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"/" withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"file name data contain %@",fileName);
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    //see if Data.plist exists in the Documents directory
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[self saveMyPath:fileName] ]) {
       [fileManager copyItemAtPath:path toPath:[self saveMyPath:@""] error:nil]; //at this point the app crashes saying path is null
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is called in the background, you should create your own `NSAutorealsePool`. For example:

```
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    // your code
    [pool drain];
```

Comment: calendar.plist is the one you created? Can you post mode code?